# How to extend a choice in xs:complexType

Tags: xml, xsd

I have this small XML-Schema. Is it possible to extend the "contentType" instead of duplicate it's content?

I think a pitfall is that "contentWithInputType"-elements can contain further "contentWithInputType"-elements but "contentType"-elements can only contain "contentType"-elements.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://meinnamespace.meinefirma.de" targetNamespace="http://meinnamespace.meinefirma.de" elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:element name="ROOTNODE">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element name="content" type="contentType" />
                <xs:element name="contentWithInput" type="contentWithInputType" />
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:complexType name="contentType" mixed="true">
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element name="span" type="contentType" />
            <xs:element name="b" type="contentType" />
            <xs:element name="i" type="contentType" />
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="contentWithInputType" mixed="true">
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element name="span" type="contentWithInputType" />
            <xs:element name="b" type="contentWithInputType" />
            <xs:element name="i" type="contentWithInputType" />
            <xs:element name="input" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you not have:

```
<xs:complexType name="contentWithInputType" mixed="true">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="content" type="contentType" />
        <xs:element name="input" type="contentWithInputType" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

This is semantically similar to what you require.

Ultimately you cannot "extend" types in XSD in the same sense you would extend a type in obejct orientation.

Comment: you fell in my pitfall, the content within contentWithInputType can contain contentWithInputType and not only contentType

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should be using substitution groups. Declare an abstract element called `inline`; make this the only element allowed in `contentType`; then define elements `span`, `i`, `b`, etc with `substitutionGroup="inline"`.

Another useful technique is named model groups. Define an `xs:group` containing a fragment of content model that is to be used repeatedly, and then refer to it where needed using `xs:group ref="group-name"`.